# How do I use the groupby key as an xticklabel in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

**Here is my code so far:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('albums.csv')

group = df.groupby('genre')
data = group.aggregate(np.average)


labels = group.genre
rolling_stone_mean = data.iloc[:, 5]
mtv_mean = data.iloc[:, 6]
music_maniac_mean = data.iloc[:, 7]

x = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.25

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/1, rolling_stone_mean, width, label = 'Rolling Stone')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/1, mtv_mean, width, label = 'MTV')
rects3 = ax.bar(x, music_maniac_mean, width, label = 'Music Maniac')

ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by Genre and critic')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.set_xlabel('Genre')
ax.legend()

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

I know it's the following bit that is wrong.

```
labels. = group.genre
```

Essentially I'm trying to use the column that has been used to group as the xticklabel, but can't figure it out, as it doesn't seem like it's part of the dataframe.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for

`labels = list(group.groups.keys())`

The "label" is still part of the DataFrame but group is not a DataFrame object, it is a groupby object; `group.groups` will give you a dictionary of labels and indexes for those labels